# reoder basis vectors to get 'more diagonal' representation of NxM matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to reorder the basis vectors of an NxM matrix in a way that leads to a representation with 'as much weight close to the diagonal as possible'. I would be happy, if instead of a matrix looking like that
[image: start]

I would like it to look like that:

[image]

I know this is pretty hand-wavy, but I hope you can get the idea...

I am sure there are plenty of ways to do that, but I wasn't able to come up with any good search terms, probably because I am unable to formulate the problem precisely.

Do you know any algorithm that does this? (it doesn't have to be efficient it is just on the magnitude of a 1000x1000 matrix).

I also posted a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657004/ideal-arrangement-of-entries-in-confusion-matrix) but it didn't get much coverage, so I rethought and posted here.

Comment: see pages 174-175 of http://www.supermath.info/LinearNotes2015.pdf essentially the idea is to choose the inverse image of the range basis to start your domain basis then stick the basis for the kernel at the end. This gives you an identity matrix padded with zeros.

Comment: If I understand correctly this replaces the basis by completely new vectors right? What I want to do is just reorder my existing basis to get a more compact representation.

Comment: I see, well, I guess you need to decide what is first then sort through your columns and select all the first columns and put them at the start of your new list. Then, look for what comes next according to the order as indicated by the pixelation scheme. Put all those second.... keep sorting until  you have them all in a nice tidy list.

Comment: thanks for your comment! so I basically choose one coordinate (in this case collumns) and reorder them, but I leave the rows untouched? How does this ensure that the weight is concentrated close to the middle?